# submit an app to iTunes without owning the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

Can I submit an iPad app without owning a iPad?  In other words can I build and compile an app without the device and submit it.  Obviously without the device the build will Fail.  Or is there a way around this with the simulator builds?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.

You can't submit simulator builds because they are compiled for Intel and not ARM, but you don't need an iPad to build and iPad app.

If you set up your certificates and provisioning profiles properly, the build will NOT fail even if you don't have the device.

Comment: It's generally wise to have one, though, to test on. The simulator is a good but not perfect emulator of iOS code, and it runs much faster than the iPad's processor.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build with "iOS Device" and get a working app.